# Clams frozen before purging

Tags: food-safety, frozen, seafood, mussels, clams

I got excited to find out my friends family vacation home is on a river where a ton of delicious clams live. TI caught a bunch of live clams, then hastily put the whole lot in a bag of water and threw that in the freezer while making dinner with my friends.

I didn't realize that freezing them would kill them and make it impossible to purge them.

Is the whole lot spoiled now? Is there still some way to eat them?

Comment: If you cant eat them, bury them in the garden like I did with the fish I forgot in the back of the van.  The plants above those fish are very happy.

Answer (score 13):

There’s no way to make a dead clam purge sand etc.

You can always try to cook a few and see how gritty they really are, then decide. You may be lucky and find that they have a good mouthfeel, or you may find out that your entire catch inedible and needs to be discarded.